# How to make my mysql queries for showing friends feeds?

Tags: mysql

Here is my table structure.(fun_friends)

```
id user_id,friend_id,status,createdat,updatedat
 1    1        2        1      123456  125461
 2    1        3        1      454545  448788
 3    2        4        1      565659  898889
 4    1        5        1      877878  878788
```

Here is the table structure of user_uploads

```
id  user_id parent_id   category_id title   slug    tags    description video_type  source  video_link  video_thumb
 1     2        1              2    fun     fun     ['4','5']  coolvid     1        ytu     link        thumb
```

I need to show the latest upload of my friends

Can you tell me how can i join this tables together? i tried with

```
SELECT * FROM fun_friends WHERE (user_id= '".$_SESSION['user_row_id']."' AND  `status` =1) OR (friend_id= '".$_SESSION['user_row_id']."' AND  `status` =1)
```

and it is showing all friends of logged-in user

Comment: what ios your desired output?

Comment: My expected output is (if my user id is 2 ) i have two friends (4,1) i need to show the videos uploaded by the user which 4,1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

how about using `UNION` to get the friends user and wrapping it inside a subquery which later join on the other tabel,

```
SELECT  usr.*
FROM    user_uploads usr
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_ID  AS ID
            FROM    Fun_Friends
            WHERE   friend_ID = 'ID_HERE'
            UNION
            SELECT  friend_ID As ID
            FROM    Fun_Friends
            WHERE   ser_ID = 'ID_HERE'
        ) idList ON usr.user_ID = idList.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just join both table using user_id field. sample query bellow will return one record with latest user_uploads.id.

```
select * 
from fun_friends a 
inner join user_uploads b on a.user_id = b.user id 
order by b.id desc limit 0,1
```

Comment: But this query is only join with user_id. if the friend request sented by another user to me my id is in friend_id field and that user id is in user_id field. so how can i get that user?